# Python 3: Convert CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x

My csv file is like this,

```
1,no,apple,water
2,,grape,
3,yes,,coke
4,no,orange,water
5,no,,water
```

with some blanks in it

and I'm trying to convert this file to list of dictionaries, which should be,

```
[{'id': '1', 'yesno': 'no', 'fruit': 'apple', 'drink': 'water'}, 
{'id': '2', 'fruit': 'grape'}, 
{'id': '3', 'yesno': 'yes', 'drink': 'coke'}, 
{'id': '4', 'yesno': 'no', 'fruit': 'orange', 'drink': 'water'}, 
{'id': '5', 'yesno': 'no', 'drink': 'water'}]
```

However, it returns,

```
[{'id': '1', 'yesno': 'no', 'fruit': 'apple', 'drink': 'water'}, 
{'id': '2', 'yesno': 'no', 'fruit': 'grape', 'drink': 'water'}, 
{'id': '3', 'yesno': 'yes', 'fruit': 'grape', 'drink': 'coke'}, 
{'id': '4', 'yesno': 'no', 'fruit': 'orange', 'drink': 'water'}, 
{'id': '5', 'yesno': 'no', 'fruit': 'orange', 'drink': 'water'}]
```

It seems like the blank values are filled with the copied one from the previous dictionary

Here is my code,

```
import csv
def data(file):
    header = ['id', 'yesno', 'fruit', 'drink']
    list_data = []
    dict_record = {}
    var = 0
    csv_r = list(csv.reader(open(file)))
    while var < len(csv_r):
        for i in range(4): #since there are 4 fields
            if csv_r[var][i] != '':
                dict_record[header[i]] = csv_r[var][i]
        list_data.append(dict_record.copy())
        var = var + 1
    return(list_data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python comes with a `csv` parser, don't re-invent the wheel:

```
In [1]: import csv

In [2]: with open('example.csv') as f:
   ...:     reader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=['id', 'yesno', 'fruit', 'drink'])
   ...:     data = list(reader)
   ...:

In [3]: data
Out[3]:
[{'drink': 'water', 'fruit': 'apple', 'id': '1', 'yesno': 'no'},
 {'drink': '', 'fruit': 'grape', 'id': '2', 'yesno': ''},
 {'drink': 'coke', 'fruit': '', 'id': '3', 'yesno': 'yes'},
 {'drink': 'water', 'fruit': 'orange', 'id': '4', 'yesno': 'no'},
 {'drink': 'water', 'fruit': '', 'id': '5', 'yesno': 'no'}]
```

> It seems like the blank values are filled with the copied one from the previous dictionary

There *is no previous dictionary*, fundamentally the problem with your approach is that you *keep reusing the same dictionary*, so of course the old values are always there. Just use a new dictionary:

```
In [6]: with open('example.csv') as f:
   ...:     data = []
   ...:     names = ['id', 'yesno', 'fruit', 'drink']
   ...:     for line in f:
   ...:         items = line.strip().split(',')
   ...:         data.append({k:v for k,v in zip(names, items)})
   ...:
   ...:

In [7]: data
Out[7]:
[{'drink': 'water', 'fruit': 'apple', 'id': '1', 'yesno': 'no'},
 {'drink': '', 'fruit': 'grape', 'id': '2', 'yesno': ''},
 {'drink': 'coke', 'fruit': '', 'id': '3', 'yesno': 'yes'},
 {'drink': 'water', 'fruit': 'orange', 'id': '4', 'yesno': 'no'},
 {'drink': 'water', 'fruit': '', 'id': '5', 'yesno': 'no'}]
```

And if you *really* don't want to include the empty fields, you can do something like:

```
In [8]: with open('example.csv') as f:
   ...:     data = []
   ...:     names = ['id', 'yesno', 'fruit', 'drink']
   ...:     for line in f:
   ...:         items = line.strip().split(',')
   ...:         data.append({k:v for k,v in zip(names, items) if v})
   ...:

In [9]: data
Out[9]:
[{'drink': 'water', 'fruit': 'apple', 'id': '1', 'yesno': 'no'},
 {'fruit': 'grape', 'id': '2'},
 {'drink': 'coke', 'id': '3', 'yesno': 'yes'},
 {'drink': 'water', 'fruit': 'orange', 'id': '4', 'yesno': 'no'},
 {'drink': 'water', 'id': '5', 'yesno': 'no'}]
```

General advice: don't use while-loops when you can *easily* use a for-loop. File-objects are iterable, just do `for line in f:`, and for that matter, always use a `with` statement to use files (i.e. use context-managers), and don't materialize the whole thing, i.e. don't do `list(csv.reader(open(file)))` unless you actually want a list-of-lines. Also, don't use index-based loops if you don't have to, learn about the handy iterators in python, like `enumerate` and `zip`.

Even **better yet**, *don't reinvent the wheel*:

```
In [10]: with open('example.csv') as f:
    ...:     reader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=['id', 'yesno', 'fruit', 'drink'])
    ...:     data = [{k:v for k,v in row.items() if v} for row in reader]
    ...:

In [11]: data
Out[11]:
[{'drink': 'water', 'fruit': 'apple', 'id': '1', 'yesno': 'no'},
 {'fruit': 'grape', 'id': '2'},
 {'drink': 'coke', 'id': '3', 'yesno': 'yes'},
 {'drink': 'water', 'fruit': 'orange', 'id': '4', 'yesno': 'no'},
 {'drink': 'water', 'id': '5', 'yesno': 'no'}]
```

Comment: what if I don't want to print out the keys with blank values?

Comment: ex. from the 2nd dictionary, from {'drink': '', 'fruit': 'grape', 'id': '2', 'yesno': ''} to  {'drink': '', 'fruit': 'grape', 'id': '2'} only

Comment: @JGee you can always filter later. Honestly, I don't know why you would want that.